# Слово "бессилье"

Tags: лексика

Уважаемые! З.Гиппиус словом "Бессилье" озаглавила своё стихотворение. Не могу это слово найти в словарях. Оно, что признанно вне "закона"? У современных авторов оно употребляется (Стихи.ру). Хочу его вставить в четверостишие:
*Господин опечалился сильно.

Что природой я был обделЁн.

Заскрипел он зубами в бессилье.

От досады, что скуден ум мой.*
Помогите определиться. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *бессилье* не представлено в большинстве нормативных словарей, ибо не нуждается в словарной фиксации. *Бессилье, прощенье, четверостишье* и подоб. – не особые слова, а лишь **орфографические варианты** соответствующих слов на *-ие: бессилие, прощение, четверостишие* и проч. Если учесть, что формы на *-ье* стилистически маркированы как поэтические либо разговорные (в отличие от стилистически нейтральных форм на *-ие*), то, как видите, использовать именно эту форму сам язык велит. :)

Замечу при этом, что будь даже вариант *бессилье* «незаконным», он остался бы, пожалуй, незамечен среди более серьёзных огрехов вашего четверостишия – не только языковых, но и собственно поэтических.